# Is it possible to use Sky Drive with linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-platform, onedrive

I'm a long-time Dropbox user, and I'd like to experiment with Sky Drive. I have two Windows 8 computers and one Ubuntu computer that I use on a regular basis. If I can't use Sky Drive on all of them, that is a deal-breaker for me.

As far as I can tell, there is no official Sky Drive app for linux (just Windows and OS X). Is there any unofficial method for using Sky Drive on linux?

Comment: I'm not sure the [tag:windows-8] tag is applicable here.

Comment: @KronoS: Fair enough, I've removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Silverlight to see the SkyDrive UI, but that is for Windows only.

You can access the SkyDrive web interface by installing a Silverlight alternative called `Moonlight`. `Moonlight` is an open-source project which implements most of the features of Silverlight.

Download `Moonlight` from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx) and install as per the instructions on the same page. It is a Firefox plugin but may work on Chromium also (not tested though).

After installing `Moonlight`, you need to install `User Agent Switcher` extension in Firefox from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/). Then click `Firefox menu → Tools → Default User Agent → Internet Explorer → Internet Explorer 7`. Now refresh the page to see the SkyDrive UI in your Ubuntu browser!

**Note: Currently, there is no SkyDrive application/client for Linux.**

Comment: Not true anymore. Moonlight is now a dead technology (http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/xamarin-abandons-its-silverlight-for-linux-technology/12797) and is no longer a viable option to run Silverlight apps.

Answer (score -1):

As of September 1st, 2013, you can access SkyDrive directly from a modern web browser. I can confirm that I can access, download, upload, and delete files to / from my SkyDrive via Chrome version 29 running on the Debian Jessie distribution of GNU/Linux.

For more of an application-driven approach to accessing SkyDrive, there's the [libzapojit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libzapojit) library that might be either usable now in gnome-documents or soon-to-be-usable in gnome-documents (see https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2012-May/msg00303.html and draw your own conclusions). If you're not against using Chrome on GNU/Linux, there's also a [Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skydrive/nffchahhjecejoiigmnhhicpoabngedk?hl=en-US), though I haven't tested it on my own machine.